# Can a Catholic Priest report a murderer's confession?

Tags: catholicism, confession

This is merely a hypothetical, and I realize how unlikely this is, but if a person who committed murder confessed it to a Catholic priest, is the priest then allowed to go report the crime to the police? Is there a code that the priest won't confess sins to others?

It seems to me that the greater sin would be to not report the crime and let justice fly out the door, not to break some code.

---

Related: [Can a priest act on a confession of molestation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/61742/can-a-priest-act-on-a-confession-of-molestation)

Comment: The question is about a conflict between religious laws and civil laws. The laws of Catholicism are defined by a supranational institution, but the latter are country-specific. Answers will probably differ depending on whether the priest practices in a country that has special rules for Catholic confessions and a country without such rules, e.g. a country with no provisions for freedom of religion.

Comment: Not only priests, but therapists don't report crimes either (though they may report if they believe there's an ongoing future risk).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, he cannot. That would be a violation of the seal of confession, which is that a priest cannot reveal anything that would betray the penitent.

> [Can.  983](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3G.HTM) §1. The sacramental seal is inviolable; therefore it is absolutely forbidden for a confessor to betray in any way a penitent in words or in any manner [e.g., by signs] and for any reason.
>
> [Can. 984](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P3G.HTM) §1. A confessor is prohibited completely from using knowledge acquired from confession to the detriment of the penitent even when any danger of revelation is excluded.
> §2. A person who has been placed in authority cannot use in any manner for external governance the knowledge about sins which he has received in confession at any time.

<sup>taken from [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/63618/1787) to the question "[Does the Seal of Confession include saying whether or not a person confessed to them?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/63617/1787)"</sup>

Comment: So he just has to… shut up about it? That seems wrong to me. I understand the seriousness of keeping confession private, but it still seems wrong.

Comment: @LukeHill Priests usually forget about what they've heard in confession anyways. Why does it "seems wrong" to you? Civil law in many places even protects priests regarding the seal of confession.

Comment: @LukeHill It seems wrong because it IS wrong. Has no one read Romans 13:1-5? You can't just ignore the Bible.

Comment: @Geremia I doubt a priest would forget a murder confession. It seems wrong because it seems to deprive justice by removing a key witness.

Comment: @Rajesh that’s not an argument against confession. That verse does not mean that the government should be submitted to at all times regardless of the commands.

Comment: @LukeHill Confessors regularly hear way worse sins than murder. Also, good confessors do not take who it the penitent is into account but what the sins (the matter of confession) are.

Comment: @Geremia Understood. I don’t think I have a problem with it, it just feels wrong. But emotions ought not hinder the truth.

Comment: Each case needs to be weighed on merit. Imagine this case:  : X murders Y and confesses it to Fr. A . X goes into hiding and Z is wrongly implicated for the murder.  Z is tried and convicted to death. Is not Fr. A duty-bound to disclose that the murderer is actually someone else , at least without disclosing his identity ? If he does not, it would be sheer injustice to Z who faces death penalty for    no fault of his. In 1966 an Indian  Catholic  priest got implicated and was later acquitted in a murder case. He is said to have guarded a confession seal at the cost of his own security .

Comment: @LukeHill if priest should report murder then he should probably report every action that is both sin and unlawfull. Why should be murder different from other sins and actions against law?

Comment: Will this legally make the priest an accomplice to the murder? IIRC not telling the police about evidence in a murder is against the law.

Comment: @Tvde1 Most jurisdictions have exceptions ("confidentiality privilege") to this for religious confessions of past bad acts, just as they do for certain conversations with your lawyer, doctor or spouse.  Confessions of *intention* to commit a future crime is another matter however and is much less protected.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - A priest can act in the case of a confession of a plan to harm someone, according to the [Canon Law Made Easy](https://canonlawmadeeasy.com/2008/12/04/can-a-priest-ever-reveal-what-is-said-in-confession/) web site, which says that “if a penitent has indicated that he fully intends to kill or harm ‘Person X’, a priest may be able to warn the police that Person X is in danger, but without fully explaining how he obtained this information”.

Comment: Part of true repentance is transparency.  If someone confesses to a murder and is not willing to take himself to the authorities, the repentance underlying the confession is suspect at best.  Murder has affected many other people than the victim and the penitent should desire to make what recompense they can.  A priest should press very hard for public confession in such a case.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks, good to know. I am not catholic myself and I wasn't sure about this.

Comment: @MikeBorden that’s a really good point. Again, remember that this is a hypothetical.

Comment: @LukeHill Yes, in such a case, the confessor must, as a condition for absolution, tell the murderer-penitent to turn himself in.

Comment: @Geremia Absolution cannot be conditional on something you will do in the future. You either get it during confession or not. You should fix any sins you committed to the best of your ability (the penance), but not doing that will not backwards-remove your absolution. The only case would be that priest will not give absolution, because he assumes lack of contrition due of lack of will to fix penitent's wrongdoing, as Mike Borden suggested in other comment.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen "_Absolution cannot be conditional on something you will do in the future._" If the penitent refuses, that's a sign he's not really contrite. Absolution is given in the confessional, yes.

Comment: @Geremia that's false. Absolution may not be conditional on the future is a correct statement from canon lawyers. Confession is about getting right with God first and from that grace, one might have the ability to get right with man. However, it is not the priest's job to evaluate the state of civil law

Comment: @Geremia see https://canonlawblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/09/restrictions-on-absolution-are-not-so-easily-placed/

Comment: @eques "_Absolution may not be conditional on the future_" event (absolution is given in the confessional), but a priest can refuse absolution from a penitent who refuses to accomplish the assigned penance.

Comment: @Geremia If, in the confessional, I refuse to do the assigned penance, the priest can and indeed must deny absolution. Also, if I don't tell the priest that I refuse but merely mentally intend not to do the penance, then my confession is invalid (lack of proper matter). But if I intend (during confession) to do the penance, and the priest absolves me, and later I change my mind and don't do the penance, then the absolution remains valid (but my intentional failure to do the penance is a new sin). That's what "cannot be conditional on ... future" means in this case.

Comment: @Geremia refuses to do the penance, yes, but it's also not the case that the penance could ordinarily be to turn one self in. Read the article I posted wherein the author, a canon lawyer, explicitly rules out any such situation.

Answer (score 0):

Supplement to the answer of Geremia based on comment of Dan W:

For *past* crimes, it's not just Catholic priests (and probably other religious professionals in general). In general, therapists, psychologists, psychiatrists, social workers, mental health nurses and mental health professionals in general and doctors and health professionals in general and also lawyers/attorneys can't.

Usually, the exception for those secular professionals is to do with *present* or *future* crimes, e.g. the client is a fugitive or plans to commit some crime in the future.

This then is the **relevant difference** for Catholic priests (and I guess religious professionals in general) : In fact, Catholic priests have the *same* obligations for *past* crimes.

Comment: Please add some citations backing up your assertions.

Comment: @Geremia It's a supplement to your own answer. What don't your citations do for my answer? I have only 2 assertions: 1 - past is the same 2 - future is different. the 2nd is already there. You're telling me I need to provide proof that there is confidentiality for the past? LOL. That should already be given. Are you the downvoter?

Answer (score -4):

Based on the prior cited: Can. 983 §1, Can. 984 §1. & §2., it is correct that the seal of confession cannot be broken on any circumstance including confession of murder.

However, there is an additional stipulation concerning murder, Can. 977:

> Can. 977 The absolution of an accomplice in a sin against the sixth commandment of the Decalogue [Thou Shall Not Kill] is invalid except in danger of death.

This essentially means that absolution cannot be given for murder, so while the confession seal is upheld no absolution is given meaning practically speaking the sin is unforgiven.  With the exception of a deathbed confession.

So the more proper answer would be that yes the seal of confession cannot be broken under any circumstance, however the confession of murder is not considered licit and will not be absolved either.

I apologize I do have the proper citations for this in canon law for case precedent in doing this, but based on my own observation & hearing the accounts of multiple confessors.  How this usually works out in practice is the confessor will inform the person that for their penance they must provide their confession to the lawful authority and face secular justice, and the serving of their time in prison or whatever the lawful punishment is is considered an act of their penance.  Therefore satisfying the need for a just punishment while also absolving the penitent.

Unrelated to the question, but for those curious there are additional categories of sin where the priest is not permitted to grant absolution without dispensation from his bishop.  One related example I'm aware of is abortion, where while normally this would be covered under the 6th, Francis has granted dispensation for priests to absolve this one.  I'm uncertain if their is a canon law citation to provide, but just a recent event I'm aware of, happy to clarify further if needed.

Comment: Then how as Paul absolved?

Comment: In the Catholic numbering, the sixth commandment is "Thou shalt not commit adultery", so this canon means that (for example) a priest can't absolve his mistress.

Comment: That's not what "accomplice", "sixth commandment", nor "danger of death" means.

Comment: Exactly, accomplice means partner in crime, and the sixth commandment in the Western number is that against fornication (i.e. not *only* adultery), not murder (any unjust killing).

Comment: " but based on my own observation & hearing the accounts of multiple confessors" hearsay at best -- other authorities are clear that absolution may not be contingent upon something after/outside the confessional.